# PHP Generate CSV Cell are not displaying on windows 

Tags: php, csv, cakephp-2.1, export-to-csv

I am using Cakephp 2.0. I need to generate a Report on daily basics in an excel format.
So i written a function to generate a CSV File. Its working fine in Linux machine when i downloads the file in OpenOffice but if I try to open the same file in windows Microsoft then there is no cells, but the data is displaying properly. With this I listed my coding

```
    $model.= "-".date('d M,Y');
    header ("Expires: Mon, ".date('d M,Y')." GMT");
    header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
    header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header ("Pragma: no-cache");
    header ("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$model.xls" );
    header ("Content-Description: Generated Report" );
```

Any one helps thanx

Comment: Have you tried to download the file first, and the open in Excel?  Excel might require slightly different CSV formatting.  An example of the generated CSV file would help.

Comment: The operating system does no effect on how to open a CSV file. If you are using OpenOffice on Windows as well it should open… Also your filename extension should be `*.csv`.

Comment: Instead of "Opening" the file with Excel look for "Importing the data".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might doing something wrong here Please check your header. You have mentioned csv in the question and you're writing excel header. That is might be confusing `MS Excel`

```
header ("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$model.xls" );
header ("Content-Description: Generated Report" );
```

I'm using this kind of header format which is perfectly working for me in windows and as well as in Open office. Please give a try with this.

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-type: octet/stream");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($filename.".csv"));
header("refresh: 0; url= ".$redirect_url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Excel CSV files should be named SSV files, because the data columns need to be separated by a semicolon instead of a comma. Also the data should be enclosed in quotes and any inner quotes need to be escaped as double quote; e.g. `1;"Some ""string"" with escapes"`.